# How do I remove all objects from an NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I need to remove all objects from an `NSMutableArray`. I can't seem to do this by enumerating as the code crashes.

Can anyone tell me the best way to do this with a code example if possible?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[myArray removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work anymore... i think it is the latest version of Xcode

Comment: @Marci-man There must be a problem with the rest of your code - I assure you, this method still works.

Comment: But make sure that your operation is thread-safe. In multi-threading apps you have to make safe access (reading and writing) to mutable collections (for example, using dispatch barriers or locks,mutaxes)

Comment: @malex there are far better data structures to use in a multithreaded environment than the `NS*` ones. Should you truly need to access objects in your data structure across threads, there are several wonderful lock-free C++ libraries that will do so far more efficiently than any jerry-rigged semaphore or barrier approach.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, could you give some links with straightforward incorporation in obj-c code?

Comment: @malex Objective-C is 100% compatible with C++ source, just change your extension to .mm and use whichever library fits your needs. Some good places to start might be Boost.LockFree, libcds, but there are plenty of others available should you do some searching.

Answer (score 2):

1.Create instance of NSMutableArray in .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* arrayEmployee;
```

2.@synthesize in .m file

```
@synthesize arrayEmployee;
```

3.Remove all objects from an NSMutableArray

```
[self.arrayEmployee removeAllObjects];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3:

```
yourArry.removeAllObjects()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  // In Swift     

 arrayName.removeAllObjects()
```

Answer (score -2):

in case [YourArray removeAllObjects]; doesn't work.

Then do it manually as below:

```
int c = (int)[YourArray count]-1;
for (int l = 0; l <= c; l++) {[YourArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];}
```

Comment: explain me why. its what i'm using for years on all my apps. works great for me